# VirtualHost is not taken as the best match

Tags: apache, virtualhost

I have a file called **pga-default.conf** which looks like,

```
<VirtualHost *:8008>
    ServerName 192.168.1.10

    DocumentRoot /var/www/portals/default/public

    <Directory "/var/www/portals/default/public">
       AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/default.error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/default.requests.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Problem is whenever I try with http://192.168.1.10:8008 it always loads the default Apache Testing page. 
**default.conf** looks like,

```
Listen 8008
<VirtualHost _default_:8008>
    DocumentRoot "/www/default"
</VirtualHost>
```

But when I change the `<VirtualHost *:8008>` into `<VirtualHost 192.168.1.10:8008>` in **pga-default.conf** it works as expected. I want to know why is this. As far as I know, this is because the server doesn't pick the VirtualHost as the best match for the particular IP address and port.

I tried several other methods as well, but none of them worked except the above-mentioned method. Following are the other methods. (Changes for **pga-default.conf**)

- Change `ServerName 192.168.1.10` to `ServerName 192.168.1.10:8008`
- Used `ServerAlias 192.168.1.10`

**Note** - With the above configuration `<VirtualHost *:8008>` some of my colleagues have received successful results. This problem occurred only for me.

What have I missed here? How come others getting the expected results while I am not?

Comment: Apache tries to match VirtualHost in order, top to bottom.  So the first VirtualHost found that matches is taken.  If none match, it uses the first one as a default.  Both your VirtualHosts here match the request port.  And since you did not provide a ServerName with a domain name, Apache has no way of knowing which you want. So it uses the first one.

Comment: And from this: https://serverfault.com/questions/567320/difference-between-default-and-in-virtualhost-context, the important information is: `The string _default_, which is used only with IP virtual hosting to catch unmatched IP addresses.`

Comment: @Nic3500 yes I am aware of that, and I have mentioned it in the question. My problem is, with those configurations some of my colleagues got the the result while I am not. Do you have any idea why is that so?